# iPhone X doesn’t ring when caller is not in my contacts

Tags: iphone

My iPhone X will not ring or light the screen up when someone not in my contacts calls.  The call goes right to my voice mail.  Apple had me update software and set phone back to factory settings.  Still happens.  I removed my spam blocker apps and it still happens.  The first I know someone called is when I get the sound notification that I have a voice mail and that can take a few minutes to 20 minutes for the voice mail alert to sound.

Comment: The switch at Settings > Phone > Silence Unknown Callers should be set to "Off." Is it?

Comment: It is off. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: I wonder if the problem is in Settings>Do Not Disturn>Silence and my only options are “Always” or “While iphone is Locked.”  One or the other has to be clicked.  There is no choice to not have either clicked.  Thoughts?  Seems like I should be able to have a “never” choice.

Comment: I don't know. If whatever it's set to (on your iPhone) doesn't satisfy, try the other setting.